# App Crashing Due to Memory Warnings

Tags: memory, overflow

I have an app that has some basic viewcontrollers, with png image backgrounds, which have been set in storyboard.

It loads some images from FB, and has some animations running on some local pngs.

When I used instruments, I noticed that everytime I segues from one VC to another my live memory usage increased. When I popped the top VC to go back, the live memory was not decreasing, whereas I feel it should, as many objects should be deallocated, and memory should be cleared.

I know this is a noob question, and I have searched forums also, but couldn't find a specific answer.

Is this normal (live memory usage continuously increasing), or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks like you have a memory leek.  The static analyser in XCode will help you find/fix this.  More here http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/xcode.html

Comment: Used instruments. Was not showing any memory leaks.

Comment: Try the static analyser, it is much more useful than instruments.  "When I popped the top VC to go back, the live memory was not decreasing, whereas I feel it should, as many objects should be deallocated, and memory should be cleared." That is a memory leak.

Comment: Used the static analyzer, and it showed I had a potential memory leak, in one of my view controllers. 

Another question: 
I use pushviewcontroller and poptoviewcontroller to navigate between ViewControllers. 

When I pop from one VC to another, should the memory usage go down?

Comment: This can get a little confusing.  iOS might take memory off of you when you release it, or it might decide not to until later.  This depends on if it needs it or not and how busy it is and all that kind of stuff.  Lets say your app is using 100MB of memory.  It could be 20MB is still allocated to you and the remaining 80 is memory you have given back but that iOS hasn't bothered claiming. In this case you're all good if iOS wants more memory.  If your app is using 100 and all of it is still allocated to you and iOS wants some back, you get killed.  This is a problem debugging with instruments